# How do I group a single value as an array from a mysql many-to-many select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, one for business listings, one for dining_types, and one for dining_listing_types.

business_listings:

```
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
 |  id    |  business_type   |   business_name  |
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
 |  1     |       1          |   china house    |
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
```

dining_listing_types:

```
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
 |  id    |    listing_id    |    type_id       |
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
 |   1    |        1         |        1         |
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
 |   2    |        1         |        3         |
 +--------+------------------+------------------+
```

dining_types:

```
 +--------+------------------+
 |  id    |      type        |
 +--------+------------------+
 |  1     |   Asian          |
 +--------+------------------+
 |  2     |   Italian        |
 +--------+------------------+
 |  3     |   Chinese        |
 +--------+------------------+
```

As you can see, a listing can have multiple types, with the dining_listing_types table serving as the "middleman" table.

However, when I try to use a join on my query, I get back two records

```
SELECT bl.id AS id, bl.business_name AS name, dt.type AS type
FROM business_listings bl 
JOIN dining_listing_types dlt ON bl.id = dlt.listing_id 
JOIN dining_types dt ON dlt.type_id = dt.id
```

Result:

```
 array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> 
 string(23) "China House" ["type"]=> string(5) "Asian" } [1]=> 
 object(stdClass)#8 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(23) "China 
 House" ["type"]=> string(18) "Chinese" } }
```

I do not want that. I tried a `GROUP BY bl.id`, and I got back one record, but the other type was missing:

```
SELECT bl.id AS id, bl.business_name AS name, dt.type AS type
FROM business_listings bl 
JOIN dining_listing_types dlt ON bl.id = dlt.listing_id 
JOIN dining_types dt ON dlt.type_id = dt.id
GROUP BY bl.id
```

Result:

```
 array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> 
 string(23) "China House" ["type"]=> string(5) "Asian" } }
```

The result I am wanting:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> 
string(23) "China House" ["type"]=> array(2) ["Asian", "Chinese"] } }
```

Comment: If you don't mind getting the type as a comma-separated string, you could use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Just added more info

Comment: SQL queries return tables consisting of columns and rows. You want one of these columns to be an array. MySQL doesn't support such data type. What you are showing is not a SQL result anyway, but the result transformed into some object array (PHP maybe?). There's certainly some way to build such object array from the original query result.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [@rickdenhaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1941241/rickdenhaan), `GROUP_CONCAT()` seems to be quite close to what you are looking for. This does not generate an array of `type`s, but a comma-separated list. Another fancy option would be to generate a JSON array, but I am unsure this would really help here.

For this to work as you expect, you need to add the `business_name` to the list of non-aggregated columns:

```
SELECT bl.id AS id, bl.business_name AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(dt.type) AS types
FROM business_listings bl 
INNER JOIN dining_listing_types dlt ON bl.id = dlt.listing_id 
INNER JOIN dining_types dt ON dlt.type_id = dt.id
GROUP BY bl.id, bl.business_name
```

NB: as commented by [@spencer7593](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593), it could be a good idea to use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `INNER JOIN`s if we needed to return `business_listings` that have no related `dining_types`.

Comment: we would want to use outer joins if we needed to return business_listings that have no related dining_types

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output data, I'm assuming you're using PHP. If you're using the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) class (with a connection `$conn`), you can achieve what you want with something like this (using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) as suggested by @rickdenhaan):

```
$sql = 'SELECT bl.id AS id, bl.business_name AS name, GROUP_CONCAT(dt.type) AS type
FROM business_listings bl 
LEFT JOIN dining_listing_types dlt ON bl.id = dlt.listing_id 
LEFT JOIN dining_types dt ON dlt.type_id = dt.id
GROUP BY bl.id, bl.business_name';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $obj->type = explode(',', $obj->type);
    // do something with $obj
}
```